# Value of type <DataTable> can not be converted to <database.table name>

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, strongly-typed-dataset

We are developing an ASP.Net web application with a SQL Server database and would like to populate an ASP.Net label control with the total number of students who are enrolled at the school whenever the home page is displayed.

We created the following strongly typed controls with the dataset designer:

```
DataTable: Students
DataSet: DataSetAllStudents
TableAdapter: StudentsTableAdapter
```

In the VB.Net code-behind file I used the following code to start the process of obtaining a total count of enrolled students.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim studentsAdapter As New DataSetAllStudentsTableAdapters.StudentsTableAdapter
    Dim studentsTableRow As Knowledge_Academy.Students

    studentsTableRow = studentsAdapter.GetData

End Sub
```

We get an error on this line of code:

```
studentsTableRow = studentsAdapter.GetData
```

This is the error:

```
Value of type 'Knowledge_Academy.DataSetAllStudents.StudentsDataTable' cannot be 
converted to 'Knowledge_Academy.Students'.
```

GetData contains the query that will return the total number of enrolled students. We would also like to know how to get the value returned into this ASP.Net label control.

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelTotalNumberOfStudents" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Returns it the total number(an integer) or a DataTable with all rows?

Comment: I would like to return it as a single integer for the total. I was thinking about maybe counting all the rows in the DataTable but don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ensure that you load the data only on the first load and not on every postback. Second, since `GetData` returns a `DataTable` with all rows you can use it's `Rows.Count` property:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Dim daStudents = New DataSetAllStudentsTableAdapters.StudentsTableAdapter()
        Dim tblStudents = studentsAdapter.GetData()
        LblStudentNumber.Text = String.Format("{0}", tblStudents.Rows.Count)
    End If
End Sub
```

Of course it would be better to add a new query to the `TableAdapter` that returns a scalar value with the number of students. That would require much less resources.

Comment: The coding works perfectly. :-) Thanks for the quick reply and help.